# RabbitMQ Java client: What happens when a RuntimeException is thrown inside a consumer's handleDelivery() method?

Tags: java, rabbitmq, client

RabbitMQ Java client's `Consumer` interface doesn't seem to have anything such as a `handleException()` method.

So what are the consequences of a `RuntimeException` being thrown inside `Consumer.handleDelivery()`?

One could expect the exception to be somehow logged and the consumer to keep working for future deliveries, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't handle the exception your `channel` will be closed.

With `autoAck = false` the messages will be re-queued.

It is always a good practice to handle error during the consuming.

BTW it exists an Exception handler you can use:

```
ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
factory.setHost("localhost");
factory.setPort(5672);
final ExceptionHandler eh = new DefaultExceptionHandler() {
    @Override
    public void handleConsumerException(Channel channel, Throwable exception, Consumer consumer, String consumerTag, String methodName) {
        System.out.println(" - Error raised by: " + channel.getChannelNumber());
    }
};
factory.setExceptionHandler(eh);

final Connection connection = factory.newConnection();
final Channel channel = connection.createChannel();


channel.queueDeclare("my_queue",true,false,false,null);
channel.basicConsume("my_queue", true, new DefaultConsumer(channel) {
    @Override
    public void handleDelivery(String consumerTag, Envelope envelope, AMQP.BasicProperties properties, byte[] body) throws IOException {

        System.out.println("Received...");
        System.out.println("error:"+ Integer.parseInt("RAISE_AN_ERROR"));
```

The errors will be redirect to the handler and the channel won't be closed.

for my side you should always handle errors inside the event.

Comment: We can set a `ForgivingExceptionHandler` instead of implement another one to avoid closing channel